# Anyone give me an example to use QVector::QVector(std::initializer_list<T> args)?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, initializer-list

Anyone give me an example to use the following constructor int Qt?

```
QVector::QVector(std::initializer_list<T> args);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list` is considered when you use list-initialization. That's an initialization that involves a braced initialization list:

```
QVector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// or equivalently
QVector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Note that this is a C++11 feature. In fact, the first syntax is new to C++11, while the second could have been used in C++03 for aggregate initialization.

You can also use direct-initialization and pass the initializer list as the argument:

```
QVector<int> v({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

Since the constructor is not `explicit`, it can also be used in some other interesting ways:

1. Passing a `QVector` argument:

   ```
   void foo(QVector<int>);

   foo({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
   ```
2. Returning a `QVector`:

   ```
   QVector<int> bar()
   {
     return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   }
   ```

---

§8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]:

> A constructor is an *initializer-list constructor* if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_list<E>` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list<E>` for some type `E`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

§13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization [over.match.list]:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - [...]

Comment: If a function has an argument QVector like `Fun(QVector<int>)`, can call it like `Fun( QVector<int>{1,2} )`? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 Yes, you can. In fact, this constructor of `QVector` is not `explicit`, so you can even do `Fun({1, 2, 3})`.

Comment: `QVector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` even don't need `()` like `QVector<int> v({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})`. If I add (), I think it should also works. Right?

Comment: @user1899020 I added some more interesting examples.